# how to edit the text of combobox from another view c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have three combobx for time and I want to edit the text of this comboboxes from another view this is the code for combobpx view

```
 public partial class Combo : Window
{
    public Combo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void hrComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> hours = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
        {
            if (i < 10)
                hours.Add("0" + i);
            else
                hours.Add(i + "");
        }
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = hours;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void MinComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Minutes = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++)
        {
            if (i < 10)
                Minutes.Add("0" + i);
            else
                Minutes.Add(i + "");
        }
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = Minutes;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void SecComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Seconds = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++)
        {
            if (i < 10)
                Seconds.Add("0" + i);
            else
                Seconds.Add(i + "");
        }
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = Seconds;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;

    }
```

the second view invokes this view as dialog my problem is when I add the text to one of this comboboxes the text isn't set and still "00" the code I use as follows:

```
var dialog = new Combo();
            string[] timeArr = delay.Split(':');
            //here is my problem when the dialog is loading the text
            //of three comboboxes isn't change
            dialog.hr.Text = timeArr[0];
            dialog.Min.Text = timeArr[1];
            dialog.Sec.Text = timeArr[2];


            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string time = dialog.hr.Text+":"+dialog.Min.Text+":"+dialog.Sec.Text;
                delay = time;
                nextDelay = time;
            }
```

anyone help me, thanks :)

Comment: You are completely on the wrong path. I suggest you to learn the MVVM Pattern and usage of DataBinding.

Comment: This can be achieved through MVVM. Have a main view, 2 sub views. Include view and view model instances of sub views in main view model. Bind the combobox events to commands and properties to CLR properties in view model. Implement those commands in main view model and change the required properties. Simple as that!